# PIL TypeError: 'instancemethod' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm a beginner to Python and Image Processing and have been trying to change the pixel values of an image using the following function. However I get an error saying-
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object does not support item assignment
on the 12th (last but one) line of the code
Is there anyway to sort this out?
This is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
import math 
size=width,height=32,32
img=Image.new("L", size, "white")
pix=img.load
for i in range (0,31):
    for j in range (0,31):
        sqsum=i*i+j*j
        sqrt=math.sqrt(sqsum)
        sine=math.sin(sqrt)
        absval=abs(sine)
        pix[i,j]=absval
img.show()
```

Comment: Because you didn't call `img.load` before the loop. Should be `pix = img.load()`.

Comment: Thank you! I've changed it and the code runs fine now.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, object methods are also objects themselves - an `instancemethod` object. This means that leaving off the `()` on an assignment doesn't result in an error, it just doesn't do what you expected it to do. It's a rather common typo.

```
pix=img.load()
#           ^^
```

To debug a problem like this, just ask yourself "why is `pix` an `instancemethod`?" and work backwards from there. It leads you directly to the assignment statement where the problem originated.

Comment: Thanks! I've changed it and it runs fine now.

Comment: I've still got a problem though. When I try to print absval, it prints the correct decimal values, but after assigning them to pix[i,j] (in the last but one line of the code), when I try to print pix[i,j] it prints out all zeroes. I haven't been able to figure out how to set it right.

Comment: @VenkateshSeetha in 'L' mode, each pixel is an *integer* between 0 and 255. You need to scale your numbers to that range.